# Trying to set up a 0..1 : 1 relationship with SQL and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Let's say there are two tables in our db.

Table1 has fields:

```
Id
Field 2
Field 3
```

Table2 has fields:

```
Table1Id
Field 2
Field 3
```

Right now Table1's PK is Id, and Table 2's PK is Table1ID (which makes sense.)

Table1 may or may not have a Table2 entity related to it. (depending on whether Table1.Field2's value is 3, but anyways..)

I've set up a FK on Table2 such that Table1.Id is related to Table2.Table1Id

My end goal here is to, when accessing Table1 via entity framework (db-first, by the way), I can get to my Table2 entity by just Table1.Table2 (should be null or populated).

Right now, I have to do something like Table1.Table2s.First()

What relationship am I missing to have this First() unnecesarry?

Note:
Table 1 already exists in our DB and is used. Table 2 is part of a new thing.

Here's my current creation of Table2 leading to my problem

```
CREATE TABLE Table2(
    Table1Id NUMERIC(18, 0),
    Field2 BIT NOT NULL,    
    Field3 BIT NOT NULL,    


    CONSTRAINT Table2_pk PRIMARY KEY (Table1Id ),

    CONSTRAINT FK_Table1ID
        FOREIGN KEY (Table1Id)
        REFERENCES Table1(Id)
);
```

Even stranger, everything looks fine in the EDMX

[image]

Further, the EDXM file's association checks out with multiplicity 1 and 0..1

EDIT:

Throughout enough fuddling this works. I reverted my model and made the connection from scratch /again/ and it magically works. I'll try to think about why this work and edit if I figure out why.

Comment: your C# code of your models is necessary to see why you are getting a collection of objects rather than a single object

Comment: I'm just calling the entities like var test =  dbcontext.Table1.First() [single entity].

Then later I want to test.Table2. So really it's just the model output by EF, just a normal model

Comment: it's not the calling code that's the problem... it's the way you have the entities in EF configured... something isn't right with your models, not the SQL or the calling code.

Comment: I don't understand. If the models are made by EF (4.0, by the way), shouldn't that correspond with how I set things up in SQL? Even when I'm using Linqpad to play around with things, its perceived setup of the situation is that it's a 1..n where I still have to .First() every time.

Comment: Can you just double-check the "Multiplicity" setting for the "Table2" navigation property on Table1? Also, can you drill down into your Context.cs and grab the class definition .cs?

Comment: Yep, everything checked out just fine before and after I did my fuddling. I think maybe it was a matter of a rebuild in one of my projects I missed. In any case, things seem to work now! Thanks for the help; selected your answer.

Comment: Glad it's working now for you!

Comment: Very mysterious, though. Learned a bit in the process :) It's probably just a needed rebuild :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using DB Fist or Code First? With DB First, it should just work:

Here is an image of what I get when I use EF DB first:
[image: EDMX]

And here's an image showing that this setup does correctly give a singleton relationship:

[image: Singleton]

Also, if you edit your `.edmx` file with a text editor, the `Association` properties should be defined something like this:

```
<Association Name="FK_Table1ID">
          <End Role="Table1" Type="XOneModel.Store.Table1" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Table2" Type="XOneModel.Store.Table2" Multiplicity="0..1" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Table1">
              <PropertyRef Name="id" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Table2">
              <PropertyRef Name="Table1Id" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
```

Can you double-check that?

If you are using Code-First, then you need to make sure you are defining your relationships correctly and that you define the `Table2` member in `Table1` as an single instance property and not a collection...if you're using CF, can you post your model code?

Comment: this is exactly what I was trying to say, we need to see the entities that EF generated, if the SQL looks like the above, the .edmx should look like this.

Comment: @AndrewCounts yes, hopefully we will get to see the OP's code and figure it out.

Comment: Changed OP. This is weird. Database-first, by the way!

Comment: Things work now. Will update OP in a sec. Thanks for the help!